# selenium chromedriver called from python behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running *ubuntu 20*, I am using chromedriver as a binary that I have in my project directory with the complete pathing, however, upon firing an instance, I get the following error message below. I have the same version of the chromedriver (81) as the natively installed chromium - which is the vanilla install right out of the box. Chromium browser fires up no problems, but when chromedriver does it, I get the following error before the chromium browser appears.

```
Failed to load extension from: . Manifest file is missing or unreadable
```

python cod - very simple where I am just giving the literal path of the executable.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'/home/ne/code/Data/chromedriver')
```

I have tried removing and re-installing chromium, but to no avail. There is nothing install in chromium and I have not even used it. But it fires up without a warning message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I decided I would install chrome direct from google and removed the package managed chromium. This has now solved this very frustrating issue.